# One line arrow functions without braces - can't have a semicolon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React and ES6 syntax, and something I found interesting was that if I write:

```
return <input onChange={event => console.log(event.target.value);} />;
```

This will not work. I get a "Cannot find module" error.

But if I remove the semicolon in the arrow function:

```
return <input onChange={event => console.log(event.target.value)} />;
```

It works just fine. And if I kept the semicolon but added braces, as so:

```
return <input onChange={event => { console.log(event.target.value); }} />;
```

This works too. What is the reason for the first example above not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly understand why this is the case, let's make sure we know the difference between an *expression*, and a *block*.

At the most basic level, an *expression* is a bit of code that represents a value of some sort. So `123`, `a + b + c`, `calculateSomething()`, these are all expressions. Expressions don't include semicolons in them.

A *block* in JS is a list of statements. These statements are surrounded by curly braces `{ }`, and separated by semicolons.

Quite often, statements consist of an expression followed by a semicolon. So,

```
a = b + c;
```

is a statement. There are other kinds of statements: `let`, `var`, `for`, `while`, `return`, etc.

Now, back to the arrow function. An arrow function can come in two forms:

```
(some, args) => <an expression>
(some, args) => { <a statement>; <a statement>; ... }
```

Note the first form takes an *expression*, a single one. There should only be semicolons if you're using a *block*, like in the second form.

JSX works like this:

```
<input onChange={ <an expression> } />
```

You put the name of the prop you want, an equal sign, then a single expression in braces. Remember, single expressions don't have semicolons.

An arrow function is an expression. So, if you were to put a semicolon here...

```
<input onChange={ () => 'hello' ; } />
```

JS will see the expression, then see the semicolon after it and crash, because it's not supposed to be there.

Comment: _"A block in JS is a list of expressions"_ A block is a statement that can contain a list of statements.  _"if you're using a block, like in the second form."_ That's not a block, it's a function body. That's a huge difference.

Comment: My terminology won't be 110% correct here, I just wanted to explain it well enough for OP to understand. Conceptually, the block of a function body is the same as a block of any other statement anyway.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer as such and the explanation is great. Here is the irony: You correctly explain and focus on the difference between expressions and non-expressions, and then you get it wrong yourself. It's **not** just sloppy language, my friend.

Comment: An arrow function body behaves the same as a block, so it's not entirely wrong to call them one in the same in this instance. Still, make an edit if you feel it could be explained more accurately.